# is it possible to add a select and a conditional clause to an update statement

Tags: mysql

i have a database of students exam records based on year and semesters and i want to make changes to the level of all students in a particular year and semester with the following code which gave me an error.

```
update result
set level = ( select new_level.student 
               from new_level
               where new_level.student = result.student
              limit 1
              )
and year = '2016/2017'
and semester = 2
```

will appreciate some help on resolving this. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You missed the WHERE in the UPDATE statement.

```
update result
set level = ( select new_level.student 
               from new_level
               where new_level.student = result.student
              limit 1
              )
where #what you missed.
    year = '2016/2017'
  and
    semester = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need   a where clause  and an update with  join for join the student  at both the involved  tables

```
update result
inner join  new_level on new_level.student = result.student
set result.level =  new_level.student 
where year = '2016/2017'
and semester = 2
```

or  you can directly add the condition to the ON clause (avoinding the where word ) eg:

```
update result
inner join  new_level on new_level.student = result.student 
       and year = '2016/2017'
         and semester = 2
set result.level =  new_level.student
```

Comment: thank you so much. can see the where clause flying out. thanks again. i appreciate Raymond

Comment: @BoladaleKolade   thanks  .. but i'm not raymond  so you should comment this to the right   user

Comment: thanks @scaisEdge for the tuning of the sql update. i will try it now and give u a feedback